# Directories for docker-compose bind mount seem invisible to Dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, elixir, dockerfile, phoenix-framework

I have a docker-compose.yml file and a Dockerfile. I have a added a bind mount. If I don't try to compile or run any mix commands and get docker-compose to "up" and enter an interactive shell. I can actually see the "bind" volume and all the files.

The problem is when I try to cd or RUN an command in that directory - it's as if it doesn't exist and it "returns an exit code with 1" error

docker-compose.yml

```
        # Version of docker-compose
    version: '3.7'

    # Containers we are going to run
    services:
      # Our Phoenix container
      phoenix:
        # The build parameters for this container.
        build:
          # Here we define that it should build from the current directory
          context: .
        environment:
          # Variables to connect to our Postgres server
          PGUSER: gametime_dev
          PGPASSWORD: gametime-dev
          PGDATABASE: gametime_dev
          PGPORT: 5432
          # Hostname of our Postgres container
          PGHOST: db
        ports:
          # Mapping the port to make the Phoenix app accessible outside of the container
          - "4000:4000"
        depends_on:
          # The db container needs to be started before we start this container
          - db
          - redis
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: .
            target: /opt/gametime
      redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
        ports:
          - "6379:6379"
        sysctls:
          net.core.somaxconn: 1024

      db:
        # We use the predefined Postgres image
        image: kartoza/postgis:11.0-2.5
        environment:
          # Set user/password for Postgres
          POSTGRES_USER: gametime_dev
          POSTGRES_PASS: gametime-dev
          # Set a path where Postgres should store the data
          PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - pgdata:/usr/local/var/postgres_data
    # Define the volumes
    volumes:
      pgdata:
```

Dockerfile:

```
        # Latest version of Erlang-based Elixir installation: https://hub.docker.com/_/elixir/
    FROM bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix as build
                                                                                                                                                                                  RUN apk update && \
      apk add postgresql-client
                                                                                                                                                                                  # Create and set home directory
    ENV HOME /opt/gametime                                                                                                                                                        WORKDIR $HOME
                                                                                                                                                                                  # Configure required environment
    ENV MIX_ENV dev                                                                                                                                                               # Set and expose PORT environmental variable
                                                                                                                                                                                  ENV PORT ${PORT:-4000}
    EXPOSE $PORT
    VOLUME /opt/gametime

                                                                                                                                                                                  # Install hex (Elixir package manager)
    RUN mix local.hex --force
    # Install rebar (Erlang build tool)                                                                                                                                           RUN mix local.rebar --force
                                                                                                                                                                                  # Copy all dependencies files
    # not commenting this out defeats the purpose of needing the volume
    # COPY mix.* ./
    # Install all production dependencies                                                                                                                                         RUN mix deps.get --only dev
                                                                                                                                                                                  # Compile all dependencies
    #THIS FAILS - BECAUSE IT CAN'T FIND THE mix.exs file
    RUN mix deps.compile
    # Copy all application files                                                                                                                                                  # COPY . .

    # Compile the entire project                                                                                                                                                  
    RUN mix compile
    # IF I COMMENT OUT THE ABOVE THIS ALSO FAILS BECAUSE IT CAN'T FIND ASSETS DIRECTORY                                                                                                                                                                   
    RUN cd assets && npm install

    CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Error:

```
    Step 11/15 : RUN mix deps.get --only dev
 ---> Running in 831e2e0d3fe2
** (Mix) Could not find a Mix.Project, please ensure you are running 
Mix in a directory with a mix.exs file
ERROR: Service 'phoenix' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mix 
deps.get --only dev' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What I am trying to do - is SHARE the app directory and use the elixir/erlang/OTP libs in the container to build and run that code. This way I would have a dev environment and any changes I make are essentially saved on my local machine.

I could pull the data from github to be fair - and then commit changes before killing my container. But I wanted to try this first.

[UPDATE]: So I figured out that if I run the mix commands in the `entrypoiont.sh` file everything works just fine. I don't know why the volume isn't available in the Dockerfile and for this reason haven't answered my own question. I got the clue from [here](https://gist.github.com/dogweather/a2063b37c448584ca26be8fb69ed2b29).

The reason I wanted to do this - was to cache the `deps.get` and `deps.compile` steps as a layer so I wouldn't have to do this everytime time I ran `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "/opt/gametime_app" and "/opt/gametime" but I don't see where the second one is created. Is it probably a typo?

Also it is better to declare /opt/gametime_app as a volume in your dockerfile:

```
VOLUME /opt/gametime_app
```

This will create the folder at build time and give it the correct owner and permissions.

As for the files not being found:
It doesn't work because volumes are mounted on containers. They are not available at build time. So for you at build time the volume folder is empty. You should move all the compilation and so on in the entrypoint script. This way it will run when the container starts up and the volume is available.

Comment: yeh it's not clear.. I changed the names when trying to debug. Going to try adding `VOLUME` to the Dockerfile though - thank you.  If that works I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks again for answering.

Comment: ** 

So after trying your proposed solution - still getting missing files/folders while Dockerfile is being run...

    



`(Mix) Could not find a Mix.Project, please ensure you are running Mix in a 
    directory with a mix.exs file
    ERROR: Service 'phoenix' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mix deps.get 
   --only dev' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: I looked better at your setup. It doesn't work because volumes are mounted on containers. They are not available at build time. So for you at build time the volume folder is empty. You should move all the compilation and so on in the entrypoint script. This way it will run when the container starts up and the volume is available.

Comment: amazing - literally just realised this as well and updated the question too and you then answered the question, haha. Could you please pop this in as an answer and I will mark it as correct?

Thanks for the help!